# FullCalendar Rails Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, asset-pipeline

I am using the fullcalendar rails gem. I just downloaded the zip file for the calendar which contains the js and css files for the fullcalendar plugin. For all the tutorials on the fullcalendar gem I have not seen anyone doenload the zip file and use these files in their code (they use the CDN links but those don't appear to be working) where is the best folder to place these zipped assets into so that I can get the desired results on my calendar?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the gem you do not need download any file.

You have to:

1. install gem
2. add in the `application.js` file the instruction `//= require fullcalendar`

And to can use it.

Read the README of the gem https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails
Because you also need  `moment.js`

Answer (score 0):

**Don't install from the zip file.**

Follow the instructions at https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails#installation for installation; you will have an easy time managing the dependencies.

The steps as specified there are:

1. Add `gem 'fullcalendar-rails'` to Gemfile
2. Add `gem 'momentjs-rails'` to Gemfile if you want to use `2.1.1.0` or higher version of `fullcalendar-rails` gem.
3. Run `bundle install` to install the gems.
4. Add `//= require fullcalendar` (and `//= require moment`) in `application.js`
5. Add `*= require full calendar` in `application.css`

Comment: I originally added the gem but I couldn't get the css and js to work until I add: <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.min.js'></script> to my app and the css and js in this CDN is not nice at all